# Problem getting MyriadPro package to work

Tags: fonts, pdftex, installing

I just managed to install MinionPro and MyriadPro by following the [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) installation manual. Everything seems fine, only the pdf output is not in MyriadPro with the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{MyriadPro}

\begin{document}
\section{Myriad Pro}
This is a test document for the MyriadPro font. Make sure that all the symbols below compiled correctly. 
\\
\\
$\beta = (X'X)^{-1} X'Y$
\\
\\
$Y = X\beta + \epsilon$

\end{document}
```

In the log is no error except

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
```

It also appears as if it really uses the MyriadPro font because of those lines

```
Using the configuration file MyriadPro.cfg
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/tex/latex/MyriadPro/MyriadPro.cfg)
Package textcomp Info: Setting MyriadPro-LF sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input    line 757.
```

Had anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) +1 for Myriad Pro

Comment: You should also add `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`, as MyriadPro is defined by the package as the default sans serif font.

Answer (score 7):

As egreg already stated and as it says in the [manual](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro/blob/master/tex/MyriadPro.pdf),

> You can use MyriadPro in a LaTeX document by adding the command
>   `\usepackage{MyriadPro}` to the preamble. This will change both the sans
>   serif text font and the math font to MyriadPro. If you want to use
>   MyriadPro as your main font, add
>   `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` to your preamble.

So add `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` to your example right after you loaded `\usepackage{MyriadPro}` and the sans serif text and the main text will be set in MyriadPro.

You said that it appears that MyriadPro is used: If you have installed MyriadPro correctly, you should already see that the formulas in your MWE are displayed in MyriadPro. If not there might have gone something wrong in the installation process.

Comment: @cgnieder you are right, I will change that.

Comment: Just as a comment for future readers: starting with version 0.5 of `MyriadPro`, the `onlytext` option is set by default, i.e. the math fonts are not changed by default.